# Disable skipping of Inbox in Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-groups

I have a Google group where we send reports to a larger audience. Anyone from the group can send these reports. We send it not from our individual Gmail IDs, but from groups and unfortunately few of us from this sender group do not receive these reports while it reaches to everyone else. On further investigation I found this link https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6588?hl=en which says Google automatically archives these emails to our sent folder and skips our Inbox. Since I didn't create this filter, I don't know if I can disable it. Is there a way we can disable skipping these emails from the inbox?

Answer (score 1):

The referred article<sup>1</sup> doesn't mention that the described behavior is due to a filter; it's a Gmail feature and it can't be disabled.

The important thing to note, is that the emails sent to the group should be in the sender mailbox. Just ask the senders look for those reports in `Sent Mail` or `All Mails`. Another thing that they could do is to search for them.

**References**

- <sup>1</sup>: [Not receiving email from groups - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6588?hl=en)